# Angular how to get value from radio input

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple form in which I have input value like this

```
    <div class="radio radio-primary d-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-in-1" id="radio-in-1" checked formControlName="fitra" name="fitra">
        <label for="radio-in-1" class="cr">Fitra</label>
    </div>
```

Formbuilder

```
this.packageForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  personId: 0,
  fitra: false,
});
```

and I am just checking the value in the console by default it's false but when I check or uncheck its showing undefined

Comment: If your fitra value will be true/false than you can use checkbox input type instead of radio.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a radio input as a checkbox

Radio inputs need a value to specify what to set your form control, hence you are getting undefined when you select it.

Add a value like `<input type="radio" [value]="true"`, although the value will still be undefined when not checked, instead of false

Or perhaps more in line with your goals, use `type="checkbox"`